# Inline display of shiny::sliderInput()

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, shiny, rstudio

### Inline display of shiny::sliderInput()

What is the best way to make the `label` part of a `sliderInput` display inline (to the left of the slider), instead of on top of it?

Would it be better to do this with CSS, or by overriding the way it renders as HTML?

---

### Bonus

It's possible to generate a list of sliders like so:

```
# in server.R
output$sliders <- renderUI({
  lapply(vars, function (x) {
    sliderInput(inputId = str_c("slider_", x), label = x)
  })
})
```

... so what's a good way to make a list of sliders display as a `<table>`, with each input as a `<tr>` (having labels in `<th>`s and slider bars in `<td>`s)?

This just renders them sequentially:

```
# in ui.R
uiOutput("sliders")
```

The preferred (tabular) alternative would be more like a "mixer" panel, with horizontal sliders:

[image: audio mixer]

Comment: please quit using "bootstrap" tag, because it means something else. Use "twitter-bootstrap"